# PayPal - Continue Shopping Link/Button Doesn't Work As Before - How Do I Correct This?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, shopping-cart

I have been using FetchApp for several years to sell my digital products using PayPal. I was working on my Rails apps where my PayPal code is set up. I decided to test that code again and noticed that when users click the Continue Shopping link (when there are items in the cart) or button (when the cart is empty) it no longer redirects to my store page as it used to. Now it goes back to the cart and adds one item for the last item they clicked the Add to Cart button for.

Original code:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :add_to_cart_pdf}"), "http://mycompany.fetchapp.com/sell/xxxxxxxx/ppc?return=http://#{request.host_with_port}/en/thanks" %>
```

I did web searches and found a few really old posts regarding this problem including one on the PayPal Community website. The latest post was in 2013. Most of them were in 2009 or 2010. All of them suggested that I used target = "_self". I changed my code to the following.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :add_to_cart_pdf}"), "http://mycompany.fetchapp.com/sell/xxxxxxxx/ppc?return=http://#{request.host_with_port}/en/thanks", target: "_self" %>
```

I added an item to the cart, removed it and clicked the Continue Shopping button. It went back to my store page as expected. When I selected another item the page displayed correctly. However when I clicked Continue Shopping it did not return to the store page but added a second item to the cart. It appears to exit and attempt to return to the store page but instead redirects back to the cart. When I did not define target it never returned to the store page regardless of the contents in the cart.

The same thing happened when I modified the code like this.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :add_to_cart_pdf}"), "http://mycompany.fetchapp.com/sell/xxxxxxxx/ppc?return=http://#{request.host_with_port}/en/thanks target= '_self'" %>
```

Some of the issues I found were related to IE 8 I believe and Firefox back in the day. I'm using Mac computers and have the problem on the latest versions of Safari, Firefox and Chrome. I have not received any feedback about problems with this and I have not experienced this until now. How do I fix this problem?

I did this Google search **paypal continue shopping not working site:paypal-community.com** in the PayPal Community but found very little relating to the issue. I will check again on PayPal to see if there is anything there.

I have commented out all of my links for our digital good using that button for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted FetchApp about this and they determined it was a PayPal issue. They told me to add a value for shopping_url to set the link **Continue Shopping** returns to.

I have two issues.

1. I have localized websites
2. I have multiple pages where I use PayPal buttons that I need to return to

Here is the solution that I developed and used successfully in all websites where I use FetchApp, including those with buttons on multiple pages.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :add_to_cart_windows}"), "http://mycompany.fetchapp.com/sell/xxxxxxxx/ppc?return=http://#{request.host_with_port}/#{I18n.locale}/thanks&shopping_url=http://#{request.host_with_port}/#{I18n.locale}/#{params[:action]}" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your PayPal HTML `<FORM>`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="javascript:void(0);">
```

Cart page will still close, and the shopping page will be unaffected.